# codeigniter get field names and row values into a single string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i want to get the field names and the row values into a single string.

example:
id | fname | gender | email
1 | john | male | 1@1.com
2 | mary | female | 2@2.com

```
select * from table where id=1  
$this->db->where('id', 1);
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$row = $query->row();
$string = $row->id . $row->fname . $row->gender . $row->email;
```

Desire outcome:
id:1, fname:john, gender:male, email:1@1.com
or
id, fname, gender, email, 1, john, male, 1@1.com

Any advise on how to construct the sql query dynamically, many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->query("select whatever from wherever.");
$string = "";
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key=>$val){$string.="$key:$val,";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with selected answer is that if the query returns no records then you will not get any field names either.

You may prefer to get the field names discretely with the following command

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from users");
$field_array = $query->list_fields();
$data = "";
foreach($field_array as $field){
     $data .= $field . ", "
}
```

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of $data?

Comment: The op asked how to get results into a string. $data is just a variable to hold that string.